# jscrollpane, scrollbar angle

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the angle of the vertical scroll bar?

Lets assume we have a standard box shape, with the scroll bar on the left.

Now I just want to tilt the scroll bar to a 45 degree angle without tilting the text within the scroll box.

Tahnk you

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transforms to do something like this.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjju7/) - The CSS here is only for Firefox but you can include the other properties yourself.

**Html**

```
<div class="askew">
    <div class="askewContent">
    Hello World - I am in a box that's askew
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.askew{
    margin:100px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

.askewContent{
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: in your examle the box and scrollbar are tilted. I just want the scroll bar tilted.

Comment: "without tilting the text" - The outer box is tilted, that's the only way to tilt the scroll bars. The text inside is not tilted in my example.

Comment: my fault... i have been looking at the screen for too long! thank you

Comment: One Note: when scrolling the text moves left to right as it goes up and down. I would like the text to scroll top to bottom and the scroller moves at an angle.